# How to push a new value to a nested array in Mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, push

I'm using Mongoose. How can I push a new value to the array `fixture2`?

This is my collection. I use the `userHash` to identify this document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d2548beb1696f1a2d87d647"),
    "userHash" : "5c4b52fc2dfce2489c932e8fcd636a10",
    "fixtures" : [ 
        {
            "fixture1" : [ 
                "vote1", 
                "vote2"
            ],
            "fixture2" : [ 
                "vote1", 
                "vote2", 
                "vote3"
            ],
            "fixture3" : [ 
                "vote1"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

`fixtures` could have any amount of elements. In this case it has only 3.

And this is my model.

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var votesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userHash: String, 
  fixtures: [{}]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('votes', votesSchema);
```

But, I'm struggling trying to push a value `vote4` to `fixture2`. Is it possible to commit this using `findOneAndUpdate`?

Comment: Do you want to push to fixture2 of all the elements of fixtures array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$(update)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) positional operator to achieve this.

Also, don't forget to use `{multi : true}` in your update options, to update all the `documents` in your collection.

Try this :

```
Votes.update(
  { "fixtures.fixture2": { "$exists": true } },
  { "$push": { "fixtures.$.fixture2": "vote4" } },
  { multi : true}
)
```

But this will only update the first matched fixture2.

To update `fixture2` of all the elements of `fixtures` array, you might want to use `$[]` instead.

Try this:

```
Votes.update(
  { "fixtures.fixture2": { "$exists": true } },
  { "$push": { "fixtures.$[].fixture2": "vote4" } },
  { multi : true}
)
```

Read more about [$[](positional-all)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) for detailed information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Actually, this is the final query I'm testing out because I need to check what user is voting...

```
votes.findOneAndUpdate(
   {userHash: hash, 'fixtures.fixture3': {$exists: true}},
   {$push: { "fixtures.$.fixture3": 'vote11'}})
```

But, it only works if the `fixtures.fixture3` array exists. I think I need to make some previous validations in order to verify if the array exists... If it doesn't, I need to create it before trying to push some data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$push` to do this.

Example:

```
YourModel.findOneAndUpdate(condition, {$push: {"fixtures.0.fixture2": "vote4"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query

```
update(
  { "fixtures.fixture2": { "$exists": true } },
  { "$push": { "fixtures.$.fixture2": "vote4" } }
)
```